# NumPy eigh() gives incorrect eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I have been using NumPy to do some linear algebra, but am having issues with eigh() seemingly returning incorrect eigenvectors. [Here](https://calebsander.com/uploads/578037545/C.npy) is the symmetric matrix (481 by 481) I am working with. Look at the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

c = np.load('C.npy')
eigenvectors_h = np.linalg.eigh(c)[1]
c.dot(eigenvectors_h[:, 0]) / eigenvectors_h[:, 0]
```

`c` is real and is definitely symmetric because `np.allclose(c, c.T)` returns `True`.

Rather than get an array consisting of the eigenvalue repeated 481 times, I instead see what look like random numbers:

```
-1.03913672e+04   1.70145524e-15  -6.30342977e-16  -5.80181781e-15
2.43586988e-15   1.02142854e-13  -1.59100453e-13   6.34768223e-14
1.47793139e-14   5.19832084e-15   1.23786159e-14  -6.89332604e-14
3.35120474e-14  -5.55497774e-14   3.35912194e-14   2.41599711e-14
-8.10853045e-15   3.39728566e-14   1.66605768e-14  -4.62536283e-14
4.78158644e-15   1.05840004e-14   2.49968277e-14   6.37161752e-14
-8.29049452e-15   7.69540224e-13  -1.41737099e-14  -2.04904903e-14
-2.02649833e-14   8.75614182e-15  -6.43718154e-14  -6.71884701e-15
2.89567850e-15  -1.93639427e-14   2.05961830e-15  -2.82825321e-14
-2.99156760e-14  -1.17149803e-14  -1.00413883e-13   2.81365540e-15
-1.47420105e-14  -1.54638301e-14   2.97770540e-14   9.42616109e-14
-2.18819275e-13   6.23156105e-13  -1.14148906e-14   1.97147438e-14
-5.04103330e-14  -1.39415849e-13  -6.78032159e-14  -2.18085326e-14
-1.36511305e-14   3.09529929e-14  -9.42922227e-15  -1.80013713e-14
-3.34989389e-14  -1.31399506e-15   3.86915434e-14   7.43430828e-15
3.00681063e-14   3.15599077e-15   1.77696288e-14  -5.33198194e-15
-3.03304561e-14   1.74254787e-13  -3.31735946e-14   3.02816694e-14
-1.79965325e-14  -6.03794643e-13  -2.70964350e-14   1.13476801e-14
-1.31756179e-14   1.23490868e-14   1.31665400e-14  -4.82723158e-15
-6.80123679e-14   1.01616264e-13  -3.26409876e-14   5.00897081e-15
8.01025834e-14  -5.50605097e-13   3.03059609e-15   5.55524078e-14
1.76830600e-14   5.82590991e-14  -4.07471685e-14  -1.74936332e-14
3.67006376e-14   1.23210295e-14   4.54025070e-14  -1.37452957e-13
5.68932273e-15   3.59057575e-14   7.52501521e-15  -8.21274824e-15
2.86056181e-13   2.12632482e-14   9.50056403e-14   2.80131245e-14
...
```

However, it works fine with `eig()`:

```py
eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(c)[1]
c.dot(eigenvectors[:, 0]) / eigenvectors[:, 0] #[126.56622721] * 481
```

I would like to use `eigh()` because it seems faster and returns real values rather than complex values, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone explain why this is or what I am doing wrong?

#### Self-contained example

This example demonstrates the same behaviour within self-contained code (using a random matrix that is essentially of rank 1, except for numerical artifacts).

```
import numpy as np
u = np.random.uniform(size=(100,))
c = np.outer(u, u)

eigenvectors_h = np.linalg.eigh(c)[1]
print(c.dot(eigenvectors_h[:, 0]) / eigenvectors_h[:, 0])

eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(c)[1]
print(c.dot(eigenvectors[:, 0]) / eigenvectors[:, 0])
```

Comment: most of the numbers you show are close to `0`.

Comment: That is true, but the point is that they should all be the same, and there is a substantial difference (~18 orders of magnitude) between the first and the rest.

Comment: Dividing by `eigenvectors_h[:,0]` is not a good idea.  Some of the values in that array might be 0, or (more likely) they might be very small numbers that  *should* be zero but are not because of normal numerical imprecision.  Dividing by such a value amplifies the errors by a huge amount.

Comment: Someone voted to close the question as lacking [mcve] so I added a self-contained snippet that does essentially the same thing, without an external resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `eigh`, anymore than with `eig`. You will get similarly "random" numbers if you test `eig` with an eigenvector from the end of the list: try

```
print(c.dot(eigenvectors[:, -10]) / eigenvectors[:, -10])
```

Here is what is going on:

1. Most of the eigenvalues of your matrix are  indistinguishable from 0, they are of the size 1e-16 or less.
2. The method `eigh` returns **smallest** eigenvalues (and their eigenvectors) first.
3. The method `eig` returns **largest** eigenvalues (and their eigenvectors) first.
4. You are testing only the **first** eigenvector returned.

So you see a difference in the behavior of `eig` and `eigh` that isn't really there.

In practical terms, your matrix appears to be low rank + numerical noise. So the smallish eigenvalues should probably be 0, in which case the computation of eigenvectors is basically a lottery; there's a huge linear subspace that is very nearly killed by the matrix, anything from that subspace can pass as an eigenvector. The result of multiplication `c*eigenvector` is just a bunch of numerical noise.

Moral: Don't forget to look at the whole picture.

```
eigenvalues_h, eigenvectors_h = np.linalg.eigh(c)
print(eigenvalues_h)

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(c)
print(eigenvalues)
```